# How to insert a span inside a search form?

Tags: search, forms

When I call [`get_search_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form), it outputs:

```
<form class="search-form">
  <meta itemprop="target">
  <input type="search">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But I wanted it to generate with a `span` inside, like:

```
<form class="search-form">
  <meta itemprop="target">
  <input type="search">
  <span class="submit-icon"></span>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the source code of [`get_search_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/), notice that before the form gets rendered, the `search_form_format` filter hook gets fired. We can use that to add another filter attached to `get_search_form` where the callback is dependent upon the format.

```
add_filter( 'search_form_format', 'wpse_259716_search_form_format', 99, 1 );
function wpse_259716_search_form_format( $format ) {
  if( in_array( $format, array( 'xhtml', 'html5' ) ) ) {
    add_filter( 'get_search_form', "wpse_259716_get_search_form_$format", 99, 1 );
  }
  return $format;
}

function wpse_259716_get_search_form_xhtml( $form ) {
  $search = '<input type="submit"';
  $xhtml = 'some xhtml';
  $replace = $xhtml . $search;
  return str_replace( $search, $replace, $form );
}

function wpse_259716_get_search_form_html5( $form ) {
  $search = '<input type="submit"';
  $html5 = 'some html5';
  $replace = $html5 . $search;
  return str_replace( $search, $replace, $form );
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a class-based approach.

```
$wpse_259716 = new wpse_259716();
add_filter( 'search_form_format', array( $wpse_259716, 'search_form_format' ), 99, 1 );
add_filter( 'get_search_form', array( $wpse_259716, 'get_search_form' ), 99, 1 );

class wpse_259716 {
  protected $format;
  public function search_form_format( $format ) {
    return $this->format = $format;
  }
  public function get_search_form( $form ) {
    $search = $replace = '<input type="submit"';
    if( 'xhtml' === $this->format ) {
      $xhtml = 'some xhtml';
      $replace = $xhmtl . $search;
    }
    elseif( 'html5' === $this->format ) {
      $html5 = 'some html5';
      $replace = $html5 . $search;
    }
    return str_replace( $search, $replace, $form );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested and worked fine.

Add this code in functions.php, You will get what you want. Now you can modify search form as you need.

```
function my_search_form( $form ) {
    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <div><label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"> ' . _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) .'</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field"
            placeholder="' . get_search_query() . '"
            value="' . get_search_query().'" name="s"
            title="' . esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ).' " />
    </label>
    <span class="submit-icon"></span>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit"
        value="' . esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ). '" />
      </form>
    ';

    return $form;
}
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_search_form', 99 );
echo get_search_form();
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I was looking for a way to insert rather than replace, as [my search form](http://genesis.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/genesis_search_form/) changes its structure if it's `html5` and has variables for the attributes.

Comment: let me try again, if I success i will update the code :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a php file named searchform.php in your theme.. then just copy and paste the search form code like this below

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'theme_text_domain' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'theme_text_domain' ); ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'theme_text_domain' ); ?>" />
    </form>
```

Now you can modify the form deleting or inserting anything in the above code..